# Prove that the following three statements are equivalent regarding a set being lebesgue measurable

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

(1) $A$ is lebesgue-measurable

(2) There exists a sequence of closed sets $F_n \subset A$ and set $Z$ of measure $0$ such that $A = \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} Fn \  \cup Z$

(3) There exists a sequence of open sets $Gn$ and set $H$ of measure $0$ such that $A \subset G_n$ and $A = (\bigcap_{n \in \mathbb{N}} G_n) \backslash H$

I'm trying to prove (1) $\implies$ (2) $\implies$ (3) $\implies$ (1), but got stuck with (1) $\implies$ (2).

My attempt was the following: I tried to prove that $\mu(A \backslash \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} Fn \  \cup Z) = 0.$

Let $\epsilon >0$. Since $A$ is lebesgue measurable, then $\exists$ $F_n$ closed $ \subset A$ such that $\mu(A\backslash F_n) < \frac{\epsilon}{2^n}.$ Then $\mu(A \backslash \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} Fn \  \cup Z) \leq \mu(A \backslash \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} Fn) + \mu(Z) < \displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \mu(A \backslash F_n) = \epsilon$. Since $\epsilon$ was arbitrary, we are done.

Now, what bugs me from this approach is that including the null set $Z$ does not seem to have any importance, so I don't think this is quite right.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Equivalent conditions of Lebesgue measurable sets](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1368226/equivalent-conditions-of-lebesgue-measurable-sets)

Comment: @geetha290krm yes, but partially. (1) $\implies$ (2) is answered, but not the rest of it. Any suggestion (or an answer) would be appreciated. (2) $\implies$ (3) looks like the same type of argument but with open sets, but no idea how to approach (3) $\implies$ (1)